# iPhone webapp unable to parse JSON

Tags: ajax, json, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery Mobile to make a little webapp.

When searching, I send a JSON with the results, and everything works great: Firefox, Chrome, and even Safari work prefect; except on iPhone, which gives a `syntaxerror: unable to parse JSON string`.

Of course I've already validated the result in JSONlit and everything is ok.

You can check everything here:

http:dartsnroses.com/putio/search.html